# If same id that was in JAN-19 remains active for next 24 months

Tags: mysql, sql

Need a help please
I have below payer codes, I would like to see if the same payer code will exist in feb-19, march-19, April-19 and going forward

[image]

I can write below and check 1 by one but this is very time consuming any help please ?

```
select 'cm' as app,payer_id,date_trunc('month', purchased_at) as date,
sum(internal_price) 
from   cm_payments_transactions
WHERE 
          (sandbox = 0 OR sandbox ISNULL)
          AND
          status = 'completed'
          and  date(purchased_at) between '2019-02-01' and '2019-02-28'
          and payer_id in (3269421,
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: GROUP BY the payer and collect his months using GROUP_CONCAT.

Answer (score 0):

As commented by Strawberry, you should always produce a Minimal Reproducible Example when asking a question.

Anyway, I assume that you want to check which payers have contributed for 24 months starting from JAN-19. Also, I assume that if a player makes two contributions in a month, that would not be counted as twice.

The following query lists such payers' id.

```
select payer_id from cm_payments_transactions
where purchased_at between '2019:01:01 00:00:00' AND '2020:12:31 23:59:59'
group by payer_id
having count(DISTINCT date_format(purchased_at,'%M %Y'))=24;
```